# Plumber (on R Studio in Docker) not listening on port 8004

Tags: r, docker, plumber

I have an rstudio project with a plumber API running in docker on localhost. Rstudio is running in the browser on port 8787 and plumber is supposed to be listening on port 8004. Both ports are exposed to the host by the set up YML. Curl from the host machine shows both are open but 8004 returns Empty.

When tested from within rstudio Swagger runs and calls the r function successfully but I notice the request URL is on port 8787 (yet it still works).

However, when I try to curl the URL from the host, or send a HTTP request from VBA, I get a connection refused error message.

Here is my plumber code:

```
# plumber.R
library(plumber)
pr <- plumb("plumber.R")
pr$run(port=8004, host='0.0.0.0', docs = TRUE)

#* Echo the parameter that was sent in
#* @param msg The message to echo back.
#* @get /echo
function(msg=""){
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
  print(msg)
}`
```

From testing different options I believe the port 8004 is open on the container but plumber is not listening to it.

Other: I have tried the rstudio/plumber image but it doesnt launch an rstudio GUI in the browser.

How can I get plumber to accept a request from the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Its.. working! Turns out the issue was not in the set up at all but the request URL. The one from Swagger looked like this:

http://localhost:8787/p/113da86b/echo?msg=test" (changing the Port made no difference)

The one I needed looks like this:
http://localhost:8004/echo?msg=hithere"

plumber does not response to a curl request without the right parameters so just curling the port returned empty.

For anyone with a similar issue, to set up an RStudio based API in docker:

1. Open a port in the docker container on run/compose
2. Create an .r file with script as above and save a commit of the container with it loaded in your Rstudio container.
3. Use a request URL in the second format. (Note that "msg" is just the name of the parameter variable I happened to use.

Thats it!